# How to read a chm file from a python code running on windows

Tags: python, chm

I want to know some uses of pychm package :

1. Is this package useful only on linux
2. Would it ever be useful for a python program runnning on windows
3. So if I am writing a python script on windows and if this script must extract information from a chm file, then how do I do it.

I am also trying to install the python chm package on windows to have a better understanding. But When I execute `pip install pychm` I get the following error :

```
    chm/swig_chm.c(681) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'chm_lib.h': No such file or directory
```

Can someone explain me all these issues. It might be a very trivial query but has been troubling me for quite some time